# minikube stop doesn't stop the pods after sudo minikube start --vm-driver none. kube-apiserver still running

Tags: kubernetes

I use minikube v1.6.2, kubectl 1.17.

I start minikube without Virtualbox, with:

```
sudo minikube start --vm-driver none
```

Now, to stop it, I do:

```
sudo minikube stop
minikube stop # I don't know which one is the good one, but I do both
```

but, after that, when I do:

```
kubectl get po
```

I still get the pods listing. The only way to stop it is to actually reboot my machine.

Why is it happening, and how should I fix it ?

Comment: What is the result of `minikube status` after the stop command ?

Comment: ➜  ~ minikube status
host: Stopped
kubelet: 
apiserver: 
kubeconfig:

Comment: I just saw that pod kube-apiserver-minikube is on Error. Tried to restart it

Comment: you can use kind. It is simple, lightweight and uses docker. https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind

Answer (score 1):

`minikube stop` when used with `--vm-driver=none` does not do any cleanup of the pods. As mentioned [here](https://brokenco.de/2018/09/04/minikube-vmdriver-none.html):

> When minikube starts without a hypervisor, it installs a local kubelet
>   service on your host machine, which is important to know for later.
>
> Right now it seems that minikube start is the only command aware of
>   --vm-driver=none. Running minikube stop keeps resulting in errors related to docker-machine, and as luck would have it also results in
>   none of the Kubernetes containers terminating, nor the kubelet service
>   stopping.
>
> Of course, if you wish to actually terminate minikube, you will need
>   to execute service kubelet stop and then ensure the k8s containers are
>   removed from the output in docker ps.

If you wish to know the overview of none (bare-metal) driver you can find it [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/).

Also as a workaround you can stop and remove all Docker containers that have 'k8s' in their name by executing the following command: `docker stop (docker ps -q --filter name=k8s)` and  `docker rm (docker ps -aq --filter name=k8s)`.

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

If someone will need to stop minikube running with `contianerd`

`minikube` can be stopped with following command

```
crictl stop  $(crictl ps | awk ' { print  $1 } ' | grep -v CONTAINER ) && minikube stop
```